# How to provide multiple StringNotEquals conditions in AWS policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to write AWS S3 bucket policy that denies all traffic except when it comes from two VPCs. The policy I'm trying to write looks like the one below, with a logical AND between the two `StringNotEquals` (except it's an invalid policy):

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "Policy1415115909152",
   "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "Allow-access-only-from-two-VPCs",
       "Action": "s3:*",
       "Effect": "Deny",
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"],
       "Condition": {
         "StringNotEquals": {
           "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-111bbccc"
         },
         "StringNotEquals": {
           "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-111bbddd"
         }
       },
       "Principal": "*"
     }
   ]
}
```

If I use this:

```
"StringNotEquals": {
       "aws:sourceVpc": ["vpc-111bbccc", "vpc-111bbddd"]
     }
```

then at least one of the string comparisons returns true and the S3 bucket is not accessible from anywhere.

Comment: This conclusion isn't correct (or isn't correct anymore) for `StringNotEquals` - check [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71531863/1060004).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Never tried this before.But the following should work. From: [Using IAM Policy Conditions for Fine-Grained Access Control](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html)

```
    "Condition": {
        "ForAllValues:StringNotEquals": {
            "aws:sourceVpc": [
                "vpc-111bbccc",
                "vpc-111bbddd"
            ]
        },
```

Answer (score 21):

The problem with your original JSON:

```
"Condition": {
    "StringNotEquals": {
        "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-111bbccc"
    },
    "StringNotEquals": {
        "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-111bbddd"
    }
}
```

You can't have duplicate keys named `StringNotEquals`.

But there are a few ways to solve your problem.

#### Flip the conditional and specify `Allow` rather than `Deny` permissions

Self-explanatory: Use an `Allow` permission instead of `Deny` and then use `StringEquals` with an array. All the values will be taken as an `OR` condition.

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "Policy1415115909152",
   "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "Allow-access-only-from-two-VPCs",
       "Action": "s3:*",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"],
       "Condition": {
         "StringEquals": {
           "aws:sourceVpc": ["vpc-111bbccc", "vpc-111bbddd"]
         }
       },
       "Principal": "*"
     }
   ]
}
```

#### Use a set operator

IAM policies allow the use of [`ForAnyValue` and `ForAllValues`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_multi-value-conditions.html), which lets you test multiple values inside a `Condition`.

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "Policy1415115909152",
   "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "Deny-access-except-from-two-VPCs",
       "Action": "s3:*",
       "Effect": "Deny",
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"],
       "Condition": {
         "ForAllValues:StringNotEquals": {
           "aws:sourceVpc": ["vpc-111bbccc", "vpc-111bbddd"]
         }
       },
       "Principal": "*"
     }
   ]
}
```

#### Use a hack combination of `StringNotEquals` and `StringNotEqualsIgnoreCase`

I'm fairly certain this works, but it will only limit you to 2 VPCs in your conditionals.

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "Policy1415115909152",
   "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "Deny-access-except-from-two-VPCs",
       "Action": "s3:*",
       "Effect": "Deny",
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"],
       "Condition": {
         "StringNotEquals": {
           "aws:sourceVpc": ["vpc-111bbccc"]
         },
         "StringNotEqualsIgnoreCase": {
           "aws:sourceVpc": ["vpc-111ddeee"]
         }
       },
       "Principal": "*"
     }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it was different back when the question was asked, but the conclusion that `StringNotEqual` works as if it's doing:

```
incoming-value != value0 OR incoming-value != value1 OR ...
```

is **incorrect**.

The negation happens after the normal comparison of what is being negated. So it's effectively:

```
!(incoming-value == value0 OR incoming-value == value1 OR ...)
```

which is the same as:

```
incoming-value != value0 AND incoming-value != value1 AND ...
```

This means that for `StringNotEqual` to return `true` for a key with multiple values, the incoming value must have not matched *any* of the given multiple values.

So `DENY` on `StringNotEqual` on a key `aws:sourceVpc` with values `["vpc-111bbccc", "vpc-111bbddd"]` will work as you are expecting (did you actually try it out?). The condition will only return `true` none of the values you supplied could be matched to the incoming value at that key and in that case (of `true` evaluation), the `DENY` will take effect, just like you wanted.

Other answers might work, but using `ForAllValues` serves a different purpose, not this. `ForAllValues` is more like: if the incoming key has multiple values itself then make sure that that set is a subset of the values for the key that you are putting in the condition. For a single valued incoming-key, there is probably no reason to use `ForAllValues`.

As background, I have used this behaviour of `StringNotEqual` in my API Gateway policy to deny API calls from everyone except the matching vpces - so pretty similar to yours. That's all working fine.