# S3 bucket policy to allow access from (IAM user AND VPC) OR the management console via user/role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm setting up a new S3 bucket in AWS. What I want to do is allow access to specified IAM users and VPC's, but I also want to allow access from the Management Console via a user or role.

This is what I have thus far, which denies access from the Management Console when added to the S3 bucket.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "RestrictVpc",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpc": [
                        "vpc-12345678"
                    ],
                    "aws:userId": [
                        "my_user",
                        "123123231"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why are you doing an explicit deny as well as allows? Aren't you saying the same thing?

Comment: You're right. I updated the policy to only the deny statement. Unfortunately, I still don't know how to allow management console access once the policy is applied.

Comment: The management console access is the access for the user who is logged in the console. if you log in as my_user. Also, your condition possibly means that both conditions must be false. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46062084/how-to-provide-multiple-stringnotequals-conditions-in-aws-policy